# How do you get overlapping matches with re.findall()?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
import re

x=" tex1 text2 taxw ello how are 123 "
y=x.split()
sear=re.compile(r'\s*\w*[x]\w*\s*')
a=sear.findall(x) 
print(a)
```

I got output as

```
[' tex1 ', 'text2 ', 'taxw ']
```

in which only `tex1` follows the above criteria whereas `'text2 ', 'taxw '` doesn't have space in the beginning.
What I was trying to find out a pattern that finds

1. Any no of spaces in the beginning
2. then any number of characters
3. then letter 'x'
4. then any no of characters
5. and finally any no of spaces

Comment: What do you mean by *any*? 1 or more (`+`) or 0 or more (`*`)? Also, these items are overlapping. What are the expected matches?

Comment: Do you expect `[' tex1 ', ' text2 ', ' taxw ']`?

Comment: `\s*` matches *zero* or more spaces, not *one* or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `'tex1 '`, `' text2 '` and `' taxw '` are overlapping, the spaces before `text2` and `taxw` are matched and consumed by the pattern during the preceding iteration.

What you may do is place the final `\s*` into a capturing group and just concatenate it with the whole match:

```
import re
x=" tex1 text2 taxw ello how are 123 "
y=x.split()
sear=re.compile(r'\s*\b\w*x\w*\b(?=(\s*))')
a=["{}{}".format(x.group(),x.group(1)) for x in sear.finditer(x)] 
print(a) # => [' tex1 ', ' text2 ', ' taxw ']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/E1rtkP)

The `(?=(\s*))` is a non-consuming positive lookahead that does not move the regex index, and thus, it can match the preceding spaces before the following matches.

Answer (score 1):

To match overlapping strings you can use the workaround that consists to put a pattern inside a lookahead an to use a capture group:

```
re.findall(r'(?=(\s*\b\w*x\w*\s*))\s*.', x)
```

When a capture group is defined, `re.findall` returns only the content of the capture group in its results list.

`\s*.` *(that can also be written `\s*\w`)* is only here to consume the eventual spaces at the beginning + a character from the word. This way, and with the use of a word boundary, the pattern finds only complete words and only one time. *(and not the same word several times with a different number of spaces on the left)*

Answer (score 0):

I think a regex like this can helps:

```
\s+\w*x\w*(?=\s+|$)
```

[**`[Regex Demo]`**](https://regex101.com/r/DknffM/7)

then print an space after `a` ;).

```
\s+              at least one space before characters
\w*              0 or more characters
x                x character
\w*              0 or more characters
(?=\s+|$)        followed by at least one space or end of line
```